# Play Framework 1.2.5 Sticky error: 324 no data received

Tags: playframework-1.x

I have an application running in Play Framework 1.2.5 with multiple users.

Occasionally a user will start receiving 324 errors for a particular URL that had worked for them minutes before. (324 = NO DATA RECEIVED in Chrome, SERVER CLOSED THE CONNECTION in IE8). Once they have received this messages, they continue to receive the error.

I can see the request reaching the machine on which Play Framework is running (via Wireshark), but the request does not seem to reach the Play controller. (debug and trace messages as first step in controller do not get output to log).
I have seen the problem occur for two different controllers, it may affect more.

Clearing browser cache, history, rebooting client, restarting Play, rebooting server all seem to make no difference.

Other browsers can visit the 'broken' URL successfully. The 'broken' clients can visit other URLs in the same application.

Does anybody know:
1) Know why this might be happening, or have seen the same problem, or
2) Anybody know where in the response chain Play might bomb out or send a 324?
2) How I can trace more deeply into what is going wrong (e.g. Can I trace Netty access?)

I have searched high and wide for similar problems with solutions, and can only find some references to errors in routes file causing a similar 324 error, but these all seem to be consistent and repeatable, and related to Play 2.x. But the fact that a bad route can cause 324 errors means I would love to know in more detail what the Router is doing for these broken requests.

Any help much appreciated! This is driving me mad!

Answer (score 2):

OK, just in case anybody else sees this infuriating problem...I have tracked down the cause:

### Root cause

A known issue in Netty 3.2.4-FINAL means that it replies with a 324 response if a request contains a cookie of 8053 bytes or larger. This is known about in the Play Framework community  (see http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1618-long-cookies-with-double-quote-values-make-play-fail-before-the-request-is-handled).
You'll notice in the comment trail in there, that the double-quote issue was fixed but the size issue remains.

### My cause

So, how was I managing to generate a cookie that big? Answer: JQuery Datatable. This fantastic UI element (no, really) has a setting called 'bStateSave' that allows you to save the state (ordering, filtering etc) of the table in a cookie to improve the user experience. 
The cookie for a datatable is around 900 bytes. 
However, Datatables uses the path part of the URL in the naming of this cookie, so for every different URL path in your application you get a new cookie. 
Now just add into the mix a RESTful style URL such as /item/show/34 (where 34 is an object id), and hey-presto, one 900 byte cookie for every item you view. This soon busts the 8K limit.

### The answer

Override the naming of the datatables state cookie is not trivial, but it's quite straightforward.

First, add the following config to your datatable

```
"bStateSave": true,
"fnStateSave": function(oSettings, oData) { save_dt_view(oSettings, oData); },
"fnStateLoad": function(oSettings) { return load_dt_view(oSettings); },
```

Then just provide the javascript functions that will store and retrieve the state, using your own less precise cookie name:

```
function save_dt_view (oSettings, oData) {
    $.cookie('DataTables_myCookie', JSON.stringify(oData));
}
function load_dt_view (oSettings) {
  return JSON.parse( $.cookie('DataTables_myCookie') );
}
```

Thanks to bennybenben in [this](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/8154/bstatesave-cookie-when-does-this-reset/p1) post for the code samples I cannibalised.